# STM32CubeIDE stuck on SysTick_Handler

Tags: interrupt, stm32, stm32f0

I created a new STM32CubeIDE project for the STM32F030CC mcu. I added a GPIO output port on PA8 to enable/disable an LED. Now I tried to delay the toggle by calling `HAL_Delay`. But my problem is, that the interrupt `SysTick_Handler` does not get called.

I am a bit stuck since I found no working solution. Do I need to set up the systick interrupt myself? Or has someone a sample project which works with the STM32F030CC?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: How do you know your the 'SysTick_Handler' is not called? 
What 'TimeBase Source' (under SYS) is selected?
Where did you call the 'HAL_Delay'?

Answer (score 0):

i used  STM32Cube for stm32f103, and set like your config and it worked correctly
there isn't need to set up the systick interrupt yourself
did you debug your code?
if this lines occur

```
  HAL_SYSTICK_Config(HAL_RCC_GetHCLKFreq()/1000U);
  HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(SysTick_IRQn, TickPriority ,0U);
```

your systick should start with 1ms clock
these code are in `HAL_InitTick(TICK_INT_PRIORITY);` and it call by  `HAL_Init();`

Comment: Yes this is called, with a interrupt priority of 0

Comment: Which STM32CubeVersion are you using?

Comment: i use version 5.1.0 ,

Comment: Hmm mine shows version 1.0.1, under Help -> About STM32CubeIDE

Comment: Are you using CubeMx?

Comment: i use STM32cube and mdk arm keil v5.25 as compiler and IDE

Comment: I tried creating one with CubeMX and importing it into Atolic TrueStudio, but there I cant debug...

Comment: CubeIDE is not same as CubeMX. It is still a very new bleeding edge IDE. Unless you're interested in beta testing it, prefer more mature and stable IDE + optionally use CubeMX to generate a project.

Comment: Can't debug in Atollic? More details, please?